# dc.js: include all bars when count is zero

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I need to include all bars in the graph. Example: I have five bars (1,2,3,4,5) with `reduceCount` from score. When all bars have values, the graph is fine.

[image]

But, when bars don't have values (in this case, one):

[image]

I tried adding `.y(d3.scale.ordinal().domain([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))` but this method doesn't exist in a rowchart graph.

Comment: Do you have an elastic scale? Please share at least your code and preferably a working example on jsfiddle or something similar.

Comment: Hello @EthanJewett, yes, i have elastic scale; but i need in y axis. This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px0uae3t/).

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure. I think if it's not in the data the chart won't display it. But you could probably artificially add a null group with that key using the .data() method on the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a "fake group" to ensure that bins exist even when there aren't any values to fill them.

[From the FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#ensure-that-bins-exist-even-if-there-are-no-values-in-them):

```
function ensure_group_bins(source_group) { // (source_group, bins...}
    var bins = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return {
        all:function () {
            var result = source_group.all().slice(0), // copy original results (we mustn't modify them)
                found = {};
            result.forEach(function(d) {
                found[d.key] = true;
            });
            bins.forEach(function(d) {
                if(!found[d])
                    result.push({key: d, value: 0});
            });
            return result;
        }
    };
};
```

Use it like this:

```
var mod_group = ensure_group_bins(your_group, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
chart.group(mod_group)
```

I wouldn't use `.data()` here because it can [interfere with capped charts](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/584), of which the row chart is one. (Although it's entirely reasonable to expect it to work.)

Comment: i'm not sure how to implement this code. `ensure_group_binds` get `source_group` as a parameter, but I must include the value in `chart.group()`  ?

Comment: I think that answer is the FAQ too, but I added a little usage hint above, in case it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!